# Early returns vs nested positive if statements

Tags: coding-style

Here is some hypothetical code sample:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    if (this.CurrentElement == null) {
        return false;}

    if (this.CurrentElement == this.MasterElement) {
        return false;}

    if (!Validator.Exist (this.CurrentElement)) {
        return false;}

    if (!Identifier.IsPictureElement (this.CurrentElement)) {
        return false;}

    this.FlattenObjects(this.CurrentElement);
}
```

VS

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    if (this.CurrentElement != null) {

        if (this.CurrentElement != this.MasterElement) {

            if (Validator.Exist (this.CurrentElement)) {

                if (Identifier.IsPictureElement (this.CurrentElement)) {

                    this.FlattenObjects(this.CurrentElement);}}}}}}

}
```

Which one do you think is better in terms of readability, maintenance, etc?

Also the 2nd example can be formatted differently via the different use of parenthesis.

Comment: That's one of the worst brace styles I've ever seen.

Comment: Hehe, I actually saw some real code like that. But sorry I rushed it to type it like that, it would look better with proper bracketing.

Comment: Both are bad practices.

Comment: I'm not sure how this thread has been allowed to exist for so long without being flagged as opinion-based. For one thing, the considered "best practice" is absolutely a question of subjective taste. And not only this, but practically speaking the answer will vary from language to language. In languages with a manual memory model, or with `defer` semantics, the answer will be completely different to, say, the answer in javascript. That anyone should view this thread as a reliable source of truth is very concerning.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Early returns are much more readable.

Whenever you get more than four or five levels of nesting inside a method, it's time to refactor that method.

A single `if` with an `||` clause can sometimes be more readable:

```
if (this.CurrentElement == null
 || this.CurrentElement == this.MasterElement
 || !Validator.Exist(this.CurrentElement)
 || !Identifier.IsPictureElement(this.CurrentElement))
    return false;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting style. But how would you format it with 4-5 levels of nesting, which means 4-5 checks, right? So the above method, would you refactor it, in terms of breaking it into different methods?

Comment: @Joan: It completely depends on the code.  However, you might want to make a separate method that does all of the verification and returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks, got it. It's just that sometimes, you get these very independent unique cases that requires a lot of checks but can't easily be combined into fewer methods, but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

The first example is better in every way. It's simpler, and easier to read. Some people say that every function should have a single return point; this example shows clearly why those people are wrong.

PS Personally I would remove all those superfluous curly brackets:

```
if (this.CurrentElement == null) return false;
```

etc. This makes it even simpler, and even easier to read.

Comment: I think most people got the wrong idea of single entry/single exit - see [this post](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118793)

Answer (score 1):

I think I would write it like:

```
if (this.CurrentElement == null OR this.CurrentElement == this.MasterElement OR ...) return false;
```

Comment: So would I, but on multiple lines and with the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that the lines sometimes get really long, say with 6 checks.

Comment: You can span it on multiple lines.

Comment: @Slaks Don't know what language it is so how can I add the correct / or wrong syntax as it is a hypothetical question :P

Comment: Is there _any_ existent language which uses your syntax?  Besides, he is (fairly obviously) using C#.  (look at the identifiers and at the OP's tags)

Comment: Yes there is. No need for discussing this. Period!

Comment: Now you've piqued my curiosity.  What is it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the first is better for readability and maintenance. However, I'd probably write it something like this.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    if(this.CurrentElement == null ||
       this.CurrentElement == this.MasterElement ||
       !validator.exists(this.CurrentElement) ||
       !identifier.isPictureElement(this.CurrentElement))
    {
        return false;
    {
    else
    {
        this.flattenObjects(this.CurrentElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but isn't classes, methods supposed to be PascalCase?

Comment: I was assuming Java, and that validator/identifier were objects.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Yeah I am always thinking in C#/.NET mode but this technique is still valid of course.

Answer (score 1):

Given that in the second example "false" is the  return for all paths but it is implicit rather than declared why not just make all returns implicitly false and simply test for the one condition that is unique?

This might violate someone's style guidelines but logically is the most succinct.

```
if( e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter 
 && this.CurrentElement != null 
 && this.CurrentElement != this.MasterElement  
 && Validator.Exist (this.CurrentElement)                     
 && Identifier.IsPictureElement (this.CurrentElement)) 
    this.FlattenObjects(this.CurrentElement);
```