# nested "if"s or more "return" statements?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style, conventions

I would like to know which is better in a function (in my case a java method, but I assume it is applicable in more langauges): including nested ifs with few return statements, or no nested ifs with many return statements?

For the sake of brevity, I'll use a simple example; However, I am asking about a general and longer case for both options.

```
if(condition1) {
      if(condition2) {
         return condition3;
      }
}
return false;
```

or this:

```
if(!condition1) 
  return false;
if(!condition2)
   return false;
return condition3;
```

Comment: Or just one line: `return condition1 && condition2 && condition3;`

Comment: I prefer the return statements. But I think it is really a matter of taste.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Early returns vs nested positive if statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369822/early-returns-vs-nested-positive-if-statements)

Comment: [Where did the notion of “one return only” come from?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the "return often" method, especially for complicated condition-checking functions. To me, this looks a lot clearer:

```
if (foob || bar) {
    return "morgan";
}
if (!glorb) {
    return "noglorb";
}
if (argutan) {
    return "gahx!";
}
return "nurb";
```

Than even:

```
if (foob || bar) {
    res = "morgan"
}
else {
    if (!glorb) {
        res = "noglorb";
    }
    else {
        if (argutan) {
            res = "gahx!";
        }
        res = "nurb";
    }
}
return res;
```

Further, if I find something like the latter beginning to form in a longer function, then I'll put that code in a new function just so I can use the "return often" style.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is typically better when you begin going onto higher orders of switches.

Imagine your CPU running through a simple if check of n-1 conditions vs failing condition k (1

If you're parsing a database for 1000 conditions and fail on condition 15 then you're in for a lot of "useless" computations, just to realize my notation with an example.

Comment: There's no semantical difference between the proposed solutions. They only differ in syntax.